# Autocomplete plugins for bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

(**Pre-warning**. I'm not quite sure if this question belongs here or not)

I've just installed my first use of buzilla (v3.6.2) and I have a few issues with having to remember users names and keywords. Is there an extension or plugin for bugzilla that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a standard feature in Bugzilla when 4.0 is released.

Comment: great. but given that it was announced a long time ago any ideas on a release date?

Comment: Well, we'd like to have an rc1 in November, so hopefully we'll see a release by January if not earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I create an addon once

http://bitbucket.org/domruf/bugzillaautocomplete

maybe you want to try it until 4.0 is released

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla 4.x comes with autocomplete feature. It is made available by the YUI library:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/